# Python Code Coverage over XMLRPC connection

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on an Automation project which has some xmlrpc calls integrated with it, as my setup is based on client server model.

I want to get an end to end code coverage details for the complete project while running automation tests.

I am wondering if there is any way through which we can determined code coverage over xmlrpc calls ? I have tried working with coverage.py but it works fine for local code only. Seems it can not go beyond rpc.